# row filter with dates through datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to filter dates using rowfilter. Here is my code:

```
DV.RowFilter = "date_of_test = " & DateTimePicker1.Text & " " DataGridView2.DataSource = DV
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: So is this producing any error messages? Pretty sure you still need to use ' (apostrophes) around your values. Plus, what is the datatype of date_of_test?

Comment: the data type for date_of_test is set to date , im getting the following error

Comment: Cannot perform '=' operation on System.DateTime and System.Int32.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had bothered to read [the relevant documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you would know that you need to use '#" symbols or single quotes as delimiters for dates in this context. You're basically creating a date literal so they follow the same rules as in VB code: delimit with '#' and use 'M/dd/yyyy' format.  Also, I strongly suggest using `String.Format` or string interpolation in such cases to improve code readability.  Finally, you should pretty much NEVER use the `Text` property of a `DateTimePicker`.  ALWAYS use the `Value` property.

```
DV.RowFilter = String.Format("date_of_test = #{0:M/dd/yyyy}#", DateTimePicker1.Value)
```

or:

```
DV.RowFilter = $"date_of_test = #{DateTimePicker1.Value:M/dd/yyyy}#"
```

Also, there's generally no point to assigning a `DataView` to the `DataSource` of a grid because, when you bind a `DataTable`, the data comes from its `DefaultView` anyway, and that property is type `DataView`.  What I would generally suggest is binding the `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` and binding that to the grid, in which case you set the `Filter` property of the `BindingSource`.

Comment: thanks for your valuable feedback , i ended up using parameters to assign date value to the datepicker using value property as you mention  and finally got it to work , and i really need to start reading the documentation more to improve my code delivery